# Reputation not changing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation

Why my reputation is not changing though I am still getting upvotes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: I just upvoted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855215/how-to-test-obtaining-a-list-of-files-within-a-directory-using-rspec/2859477#2859477 and your rep increased by 10.  Nice answer, btw :)

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon true it did, but my reputation did not change at all for the upvotes I received http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931487/most-important-things-to-know-about-the-ruby-programming-language/2931697#2931697

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably hit the daily reputation limit (the "rep cap"):

> A maximum of +200 reputation may be gained per day. Accepted answers are immune to this cap as are bounties.

Or, if these upvotes are on community wiki posts:

> Posts which are marked as "Community Wiki" do not change reputation on up or down votes (but you can still earn badges).

[Source: [How does reputation work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)]

Comment: Actually, it hasn't changed at all in the last 4-5 days so I don't think its a per day cap issue.

Though it did add 100 points when I joined meta

Comment: @nas: It has, if you meant on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/200486?tab=reputationhistory).

Comment: Thanks, yes that was a community wiki post.